# ¿Cómo resuelvo un problema de MIME?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un sitio web de práctica acerca de los trastornos de alimentación donde tengo un arreglo que tiene estos datos.

```html
  export const top =[
    {
        title:"Anorexia",
        img: "../img/img2.jpg",
        description: "Es un trastorno que se caracteriza por el peso corporal anormalmente bajo, el temor intenso a aumentar de peso y la percepción distorsionada del peso. Para las personas con anorexia, es muy importante controlar su peso y su figura corporal, y hacen todo tipo de sacrificios que suelen interferir en su vida de forma significativa",
        link: "https://www.mayoclinic.org/es-es/diseases-conditions/anorexia-nervosa/symptoms-causes/syc-20353591",

    }, {
        title:"Bulimia",
        img: "../img/img3.jpg",
        description: "Es un trastorno grave y potencialmente fatal. Es posible que las personas con bulimia tengan en secreto episodios de atracones, es decir, que coman grandes cantidades de alimentos y pierdan el control de su alimentación, y luego vomiten, para tratar de deshacerse de las calorías adicionales de forma no saludable",
        link: "https://www.mayoclinic.org/es-es/diseases-conditions/bulimia/symptoms-causes/syc-20353615",
    }, 
    {
        title:"Trastorno alimentario convulsivo",
        img: "../img/img4.jpg",
        description: "Es un trastorno grave, habitualmente signiica comer en exceso (llamado también atracón) Puedes comer con rapidez o consumir más alimentos de los que tienes pensado, incluso cuando no tienes apetito, y seguir comiendo mucho tiempo después de sentirte demasiado lleno",
        link: "https://www.mayoclinic.org/es-es/diseases-conditions/bulimia/symptoms-causes/syc-20353615",
    }
];
```

De estos datos, quiero que se guarden en un constructor, es decir, con el uso de POO, que va algo así.

```js
import {top} from "../top";
//Principal container - top left
export class TopInfo {
  constructor(title, img, desc, link) {
    this.title = title;
    this.img = img;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.link = link;
  }
}

const datos = top.map(data => TopInfo(data.title, data.img, data.description, data.link));
console.log(datos);
```

En sí en el código no tengo problema, realizo un map porque nesesito esa información para un nuevo arreglo, pero quiero ver que la información se guarde y se imprima, pero a la hora de correrlo, me sale esto como error de MIME:
GEThttp://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgramaAlimentacion/js/top
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgramaAlimentacion/js/top” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).

Este es mi código de HTML

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="./img/Imagen_logo.png"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>SaveYourBody</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="header__options">
        <div class="header__options-logo">
          <img src="./img/logo3.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">¿Qué es un trastorno alimenticio?</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Origen</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Consecuencias</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
      <div id="home"></div>
      <div id="mean"></div>
      <div id="origin"></div>
      <div id="consequences"></div>
      <div class="us"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="info__top">
      <div class="info__top-card">
        <h3 id="info__top-title"><!-- Bulimia --></h3>
        <img src="" id="info__top-img"/>
        <p id="info__top-des"><!-- Es un trastorno que se caracteriza por el peso corporal anormalmente bajo, el temor intenso a aumentar de peso y la percepción distorsionada del peso. Para las personas con anorexia, es muy importante controlar su peso y su figura corporal, y hacen todo tipo de sacrificios que suelen interferir en su vida de forma significativa --></p>
        <a href="" target="_blank" id="info__top-link">Leer más</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer></footer>
  </body>
  <script src="./js/TopInfo/topInfo.js" type="module"></script>
```

En ortro proyecto ya había tenido este problema, pero lo resolví añadiendo type="module" en el enlace de script, pero ahora ya no sé que hacer. ¿Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: ¿La ruta `http://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgramaAlimentacion/js/top` es correcta?

Comment: Si, ese el de top es el arreglo, ocupa un js para sí solo

Comment: ME acabo de dar cuenta que el arreglo de top es el que no lee y me muestra ese error de MIME

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he encontrado mi propia respuesta XD, por si alguien le sale un error similar, se tiene que asegurar que si va a trabajar por partes en códigos, asegurese de agregar en el enlace javascrippt un type="module" y al momento de exportar datos de otras clases, use:

```js
import {top} = from "./top.js"
```

Usar siempre los enlaces con su respectivo formato, en mi caso .js

Comment: Puedes marcar ésta respuesta ✓ para que quede cerrada tu pregunta indicando que ésta es la solución

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz No puede hasta pasadas x horas (creo que son entre 24 y 48 horas) :-)

Comment: @AnaPaiz Tu respuesta indica que tenias mal la ruta, pues has cambiado los dos puntos **..**  por solo uno **.** como te sugería al preguntarte si la ruta era correcta. Otra cosa sería si es necesario o no la extensión **js** que has puesto, eso ya no lo sé, pero quizás sí.

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Aquí explican lo que ocurre cuando das tu propia respuesta y lo de las horas para la aceptación que decia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Gracias @masterguru